# Compactness or Connectedness of $A \subseteq \Bbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, connectedness

Consider the subsets A and B of $\Bbb R^2$ defined by $A = \{\left(x,x\sin\frac1x\right):x \in(0,1]\}$ and $B=A \cup \{(0,0)\}.$ Then

1. A is compact.
2. A is connected.
3. B is compact.
4. B is connected.

We know that

(1) If A and B are connected sets then $A \cup B$ connected if

$\bar{A} \cap B \neq \phi$ and $A \cap \bar{B} \neq \phi$

(2) A is compact iff A is closed and bounded.
I have no difficulty to show A is compact set or connected set if $A \subseteq \Bbb R$ but in case of $\Bbb R^n$ I'm unable to prove it.

Since A is bounded in $(0 , 1]$ and Limit point of A is $(0 , 0)$ does not belongs to A so A is not closed. Also B is compact. How to prove it is connected .

Comment: it is not true that $A \subseteq \Bbb R$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ given by
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
x \sin(1/x), & 0 < x \leq 1 \\
0, & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
is a continuous function with domain $[0, 1]$. You should prove this fact if you haven’t come across it before.

The set $B$ is the graph of $f$, and the graph of a continuous function into a Hausdorff space is always closed. Hence, $B$ is closed and contained in a closed rectangle, and therefore compact. Since the continuous image of a connected space is connected, and $[0, 1]$ is connected, the set $B$ is connected as well.

In the case of $A$, the point $(0, 0)$ is a limit point, so what happens to $B$ if we remove a limit point? Is it still closed? For connectedness, the argument for the image of $[0, 1]$ applies to the image of $(0, 1]$ as well.